# Multiple users, single laptop, private and shared files

Tags: partitioning, multiple-users

I am setting up a Linux laptop for multiple users, Emily and myself, with the following requirements and constraints:

- Emily and I each have our own files that we need to keep private from one another (so I have files that Emily shouldn't be able to access, and she has files that I shouldn't be able to access), and there are also shared files that we both should be able to access.
- We need to bring our laptop with us to far flung places that have no internet connection, so NAS is out of the question, no matter if we can configure it to be accessed remotely.
- We are limited to using the single physical hard drive in this laptop, but we can create as many partitions as necessary to meet our needs.
- We do not need to be able to multiboot multiple Linux OS's, we just need one OS.
- We do not need to both use the laptop at the same time, it's just a plain-Jane, single boot machine with two different users.

I know I want to keep swap, OS, and data storage on separate partitions; however, in thinking specifically about how to organize our data storage, I've been debating between the following two options:

1. Combine all of our data files onto one partition, create three top-level folders (one for me, one for Emily, and one for Shared), and manage user permissions at the folder level under that single partition.
2. Create separate partitions - one for my files, one for Emily's files, and one for Shared files - and manage user permissions under each partition.

I was wondering what would be the pros and cons of each option that I describe above? I've searched and found a few other questions that discuss multiple users on a single machine, but none that specifically address my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the advantage of using separate partitions for access control; it doesn't matter what partition the data is on, what matters is the permissions.

Linux was designed for this type of access, as was unix.  Both are designed as multi-user systems.  However, there is a problem with root access allows anyone with root access to bypass security.  In fact, anyone with linux knowledge could bypass security by using single-user mode.

So, the only real privacy would be to use encryption.  You can encrypt your entire home directory, and put shared files in a separate directory.  Or, you could create a separate directory and encrypt that, putting private files there.  Depending on how many private files you have, you could also simply use a USB drive that you remove when not using it.

Answer (score 1):

To my opinion, the best option would be to create at least two different partitions for each home folder. In that folder you can keep the private files without them being accessed by other users. Then you can either make a third partition for shared files, or give permissions to a specific folder in the main system partition so that you can both access it. 
The problem with it is that you have a fixed amount of storage for your files in each user(that may be a desired behavior)

Comment: The only way a separate partition would prevent access by the other person is if that partition is on a removable drive, and the drive is physically removed, unless I'm missing something.